# How to convert java.util.Date to java.time.LocalDate and preserve date/time

Tags: java, java-time, localdate, java.util.date

I'm trying to convert a `java.util.Date` to `java.time.LocalDate`:

```
[java.util.Date instance].toInstant().atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDate();
```

However, there is a case when `[java.util.Date instance]` has day time of for example: 22:25 and I choose ZoneId like this for example: `ZoneId.of("Asia/Singapore")`.

The outcoming `LocalDate` will have different day (because that zone adds +6 hrs) as for example Europe/Minsk:

```
printing java.util.Date: Thu Mar 04 22:25:00 CET 2021
printing converted java.util.Date to java.time.LocalDate with Europe/Minsk: 2021-03-04
printing converted java.util.Date to java.time.LocalDate with Asia/Singapore: 2021-03-05
```

and I want to preserve same date in the resulting `LocalDate`'s as in that `Date` instance. Some approaches how to solve this? I guess there could be several ways.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just convert it to instant, set a time zone to UTC, because [java.util.Date](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) is using UTC.

```
public static LocalDate convert (Date date) {
    return date.toInstant()
      .atZone(ZoneId.of("UTC"))
      .toLocalDate();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`Instant` always gives you date-time in `UTC` and if you want to maintain the same date, you need to use the zone offset of `UTC`.

**Demo:**

```
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.time.Instant;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.ZoneOffset;
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
        String strDateTime = "10/02/2021 22:25";
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm", Locale.ENGLISH);
        Date date = sdf.parse(strDateTime);
        Instant instant = date.toInstant();
        ZonedDateTime zdt = instant.atZone(ZoneOffset.UTC);
        LocalDate localDate = zdt.toLocalDate();
        System.out.println(localDate);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2021-10-02
```

Learn more about the modern date-time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

---

<sup>The `java.util` date-time API and their formatting API, `SimpleDateFormat` are outdated and error-prone. It is recommended to stop using them completely and switch to the [modern date-time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html). For any reason, if you have to stick to Java 6 or Java 7, you can use [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) which backports most of the *java.time* functionality to Java 6 & 7. If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) and [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).</sup>

Comment: You were faster. Right, the `ZoneId.systemDefault()` is location specific so `ZoneOffset.UTC` is a good choice to understand the `LocalDate` same no matter where are we located.

Comment: Why we need zoneId to convert from date to LocalDate?

Answer (score 1):

You could simply copy the values of `Date` to `LocalDate` without transforming the data:

```
LocalDate.of(date.getYear(), date.getMonth()+1, date.getDate());
```

Comment: The `getXxx` methods of date have been deprecated for 24 years. For a good reason: they work unreliably across time zones. Don’t do it this way.

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry, you are asking the impossible. Despite its name the outdated `Date` class does not represent a date. It represents a point in time. At that point in time there could easily be two different dates in Singapore and Minsk. There is no such thing as *to preserve same date* since you didn’t have a date from the outset.

Comment: If you think my question is asked wrong, please propose an edit.

Comment: I think the question is fine as it stands. It’s a common mistake to think that you can get an unambiguous date from a `Date`. So your question and my answer can help clear up for future readers that it isn’t so.